# Error Shapiro-Wilk Test for multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and trying to execute a shapiro-wilk test in multiples columns.

When a try to use the following code:

`DF.Shapiro <- do.call(rbind, lapply(DF[c(3:41)], function(x) shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))`
Always appears this message:

"Error in shapiro.test(x) : all 'x' values are identical"

Or

"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : all 'x' values are identical"

How can a solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Without data it's difficult to say but maybe the following untested solution will do what the question asks for.

```
num <- which(sapply(DF[3:41], is.numeric))
num <- intersect(3:41, num)

do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(DF[num], function(x){
    tryCatch(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")],
             error = function(e) e)
  })
)
```

## Edit

If some of the tests return an error, the `lapply` instruction will return different types of data and the `rbind.data.frame` method will also give an error. The following code solves that problem by saving the `lapply` results in a named list, `test_list` and checking the list members for errors before binding the right ones.

```
test_list <- lapply(DF[num], function(x){
  tryCatch(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")],
           error = function(e) e)
})

err <- sapply(test_list, inherits, "error")
err_list <- test_list[err]
do.call(rbind.data.frame, test_list[!err])
```

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you very much for your help. In this case, my dataframe has 2046 observations and 48 columns. I divided it into two dataframes, one with 66 observations and the other with 1980. When I run for the complete dataframe it works normal, however, when I run for the two smaller dataframes the same error appears. The code that you showed me also presents another problem for me, it is showing two variables less than I need and always presents the variables of the first and second column which are id and time. Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Matheus As for the first and second columns, it's a bug in my code, I will remove the 2nd `which`

Comment: Thank you!
But what can I do if I want to include all 46 variables? When I use the same code increasing the number of variables, like this: 

num <- which(sapply(DF[3:48], is.numeric))
num <- intersect(3:48, num)

DF_SW <- do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(DF[num], function(x){
    tryCatch(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")],
             error = function(e) e)
  })
)

appears:

'Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),  : invalid list argument: all variables must be the same length'

Comment: @Matheus See if it works now, after the edit.